# MATLAB Heart Curve

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get this in MATLAB, however I am not successful ! Any MATLAB gurus out there ?

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/94020b921d.gif](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/94020b921d.gif)

I guess simple commands should work, a program may not be needed.

The error, I am getting is;

```
>> t = -pi:0.1:pi;
>> r = ((sin(t)*sqrt(cos(t)))*(sin(t) + (7/5))^(-1)) - 2*sin(t) + 2 ;
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

**UPDATE**

Even this did not work !

```
>> t = -pi:0.1:pi;
>> r = ((sin(t).*sqrt(cos(t))).*(sin(t) + (7/5)).^(-1)) - 2*sin(t) + 2 ;
>> plot(r,t)
??? Error using ==> plot
Vectors must be the same lengths.
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `plot(r,t)`?

Comment: @Andreas Brinck : Yeah ! ..... sorry !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder whether `plot` is the right command for this.  I tried this:

```
ezpolar('((sin(t).*sqrt(cos(t))).*(sin(t) + (7/5)).^(-1)) - 2*sin(t) + 2')
```

and almost got the diagram OP is looking for. I suspect OP might do even better with `polar`. Trying `plot(r,t)` gave me a squiggle in (x,y) space and a warning:

```
Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored
```

Comment: The imaginary part is caused by sqrt(cos(t)). cos(t) can be negative.

Comment: I tried ezpolar('((sin(t)*sqrt(abs(cos(t))))*(sin(t) + (7/5))^(-1)) - 2*sin(t) + 2').   It matches perfectly.

Comment: @High Performance Mark : Answer accepted, you suggested ezpolar before anyone else !

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that works:

```
t = -pi:0.1:pi;
r = ((sin(t).*sqrt(abs(cos(t))))./(sin(t) + (7/5))) - 2*sin(t) + 2 ;
polar(t,r)
```

**EDIT**

`polar` and `ezpolar` are very limited in the customizeability of the plot. If the OP wants to reproduce the picture in the question, they should convert to cartesian coordinates and use plot, like so

```
t = -pi:0.1:pi;
r = ((sin(t).*sqrt(abs(cos(t))))./(sin(t) + (7/5))) - 2*sin(t) + 2 ;
[x,y] = pol2cart(t,r);
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: @Jonas : Very nice, too bad I can select only one right answer :)

Comment: @Jonas : This is a generic way of plotting such curves, much appreciated !

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing the `*` with `.*` to do component wise multiplication. Also maybe try `plot(r,t)` instead of `plot(s,t)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>> t = -pi:0.1:pi;
>> r = ((sin(t).*sqrt(cos(t))).*(sin(t) + (7/5)).^(-1)) - 2*sin(t) + 2 ;
```

You need to use `.*` and `.^` to tell MATLAB to do componentwise multiplication and exponentiation. Otherwise, MATLAB will try to do a matrix multiplication (for `.*`) or matrix inversion (for `.^(-1)`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a complex formula on each item in a matrix, a straightforward approach is to use the *arrayfun* function.

```
% Define the formula that is applied to each element
f = @(t) ((sin(t)*sqrt(abs(cos(t))))*(sin(t) + (7/5))^(-1)) - 2*sin(t) + 2;

t = -pi:0.1:pi;
% Apply the formula
r = arrayfun(f, t);
plot(abs(t), r);
```

That gives you the idea, though you might have to fix the formula. For example, shouldn't that be sqrt(**abs**(cos(t)))?

Answer (score 1):

```
x1=linspace(-1,0,50);
y1=-x1+sqrt(3-3*x1.^2);
y2=-x1-sqrt(3-3*x1.^2);
plot(x1,y1,'r');hold on;
plot(-x1,y1,'r');
title ('MY HEART');
plot(-x1,y2,'r');
plot(x1,y2,'r');hold off;
```

Comment: it is easier to read posts if they are formatted so that the code shows up as code.  When editing an answer, use the {} button to offset code.  You can use back-ticks to mark something as code inline.

Answer (score 0):

```
theta = 0:.1:2*pi;

r = (sin(theta).*sqrt(abs(cos(theta))))./(sin(theta) + (7/5))-2.*sin(theta)+2;

polar(theta, r,'-r');
```